# What's the best way to have a button constantly get updated with a content of a web page in Android?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I am new to Android and working on an app that would have a button which would be constantly updated with a content f a web page. The problem is that during downloading of a web page the button is frozen and unclickable. But if I use .post(), to make it asynchronous, I get exceptions. Is there a way to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the official guide http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html